# I lost my mail spool

Tags: cron

I while ago I wanted to have messages from cron sent to my mail address so I installed ssmtp. But then I decided that I'd rather receive the messages in the file under /var/mail as usual, so I removed ssmtp. But the messages from cronjobs does not show up under /var/mail now, they seem to be entirely lost?

I am using debian, and ssmtp was installed and uninstalled using apt-get.

How can I restore the original setting or find the messages somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no Mail Transport Agent installed (e.g. Exim, Postfix, Sendmail) then there will be no `sendmail` binary for cron jobs to interact with, and odds are any messages that were attempted to be sent are lost. You'll need to ensure that a MTA is installed and properly configured.

Comment: I installed sendmail, and that fixed it. It must have been uninstalled when I installed ssmtp.

Comment: @JonatanKallus sendmail would work, but it is by far the most difficult one to configure. Debian's default MTA (and my personal favorite) is exim, but postfix is also pretty popular. Both are far easier to use...